# Evaluate location of relocated shell folders with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, environment-variables

Typically you can just specify the variable like that: `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads`

But it does not work if you moved the Downloads folder to another location:

[image: Screenshot]

`%Downloads%` as a standalone variable does not work. What is the correct variable for the folder so I can specify it inside a batch and use the batch on different systems without modifying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has to store the new relocated folder somewhere.
This somewhere is the registry and the following batch will read the  Registry value containing the new location.
[Reference](http://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/38708d1442867980-users-personal-folders-restore-default-location-windows-10-a-restore_downloads_default_location.bat)
I just did a test with a VM to verify this.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
Set "Val={374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v "%Val%" 2^>Nul ^| Find "%Val%" '
) Do Set "Downloads=%%B"
Echo 'Downloads' location: %Downloads%
```

So the batch will create the variable `%Downloads%` you asked for.
Sample output with a Downloads folder moved to the root of c:

```
'Downloads' location: C:\Downloads
```

**EDIT: due to spaces in the val `My Music`, `My Pictures` and `My Video`**
this will solve these variants

```
Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
Set "Val=My Video"
For /F "Tokens=3*" %%A in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v "%Val%" 2^>Nul ^| Find "%Val%" '
) Do Set "MyVideo=%%B"
Echo Possible 'My Video' location: %MyVideo%

Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
Set "Val=My Music"
For /F "Tokens=3*" %%A in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v "%Val%" 2^>Nul ^| Find "%Val%" '
) Do Set "MyMusic=%%B"
Echo Possible 'My Music' location: %MyMusic%

Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
Set "Val=My Pictures"
For /F "Tokens=3*" %%A in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v "%Val%" 2^>Nul ^| Find "%Val%" '
) Do Set "MyPictures=%%B"
Echo Possible 'My Pictures' location: %MyPictures%
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the variable globally so that all other batch files can refer to `%Downloads%`?

Comment: You **could''* set it permanently with `setx` but then it doesn't reflect the actual value, so better include the above lines.

Comment: How can I do the same for the Videos folder? `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` says the value for `D:\Videos` is `My Video` but this variable doesn't work. So I replaced `{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}` with `My Video` and `Do Set "Downloads=%%B"` with `Do Set "Videos=%%B"`but it doesnt work. Syntax error.

Comment: Because of the space in `My Video` the for command has also to be changed `"Tokens=2*"`  ==> `"Tokens=3*"` This applies also  for `My Music` and `My Pictures`

Comment: Thank you very much und Dankeschön! Works like a charm! :)

Comment: Could you explain why `setx` doesn't work as global variables with your batch?

Comment: Setx will persistently store a value in the master environment. If a folder is relocated the value doesn't change automatically you have to setx it again, if you keep track of this - no problem. Otherwise setx uses a different syntax see `setx /? |more`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is nothing like this variable.

This however should not prevent you from making it :)

In cmd you can use `setx` to set environment variables:

`setx DOWNLOADS "D:\Downloads"`

You can as well look for "Environmentvariables" (or something like that) in the Control Panel and edit it that way.

Comment: The batch has to work on different systems without modifying it...

Comment: Then another choice is to run through all drives, recursively check for the directory name "Downloads" and hope that you fetch the correct one. But there is no such thing as a downloads variable, I am sorry.