# Navigating to Desktop

Tags: windows, batch-file, desktop

I'm having trouble getting my bat file to work correctly. I run two hard drives on my computer and my desktop is on my E: drive. So %Userprofile%\Desktop navigates me to my desktop on E: , but when put into my bat file It tries to create another folder on my C: Drive called Desktop. Exactly the same spelling. But I will be using this on another computer That may or may not have their desktop on their C: drive. 
I am copying a file to another folder

```
xcopy /s "%~dp0\Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\File.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\WorkFiles" /Y
```

This will attempt to create a Folder called Desktop and drop the exe into that.
The bat is ran on a USB hence the "%~dp0"

Comment: What is `%USERPROFILE%` pointing to?

Comment: @meowmeow I suggest to append a backslash on target path. Otherwise on directory `WorkFiles` not already existing, __xcopy__ prompts if the target specifies a file or a directory. The option `/Y` does not prevent this prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Your xcopy command has a trailing backslash included in `%~dp0` so there is one too much. Replace with:

```
xcopy /s /Y "%~dp0Folder\Folder\Folder\Folder\File.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\WorkFiles\"
```

---

If you relocated your Desktop from the normal position you have to lookup the actual location in the registry (or PowerShell/vbscript user shell folders)
If the Desktop is not relocated, this batch will nevertheless get the proper location:

```
Set "Key=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"
Set "Val=Desktop"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%A in (
  'Reg Query "%Key%" /v "%Val%" 2^>Nul ^| Find "%Val%" '
) Do Set "Desktop=%%B"
Echo 'Desktop' location: %Desktop%
```

The better way to evaluate the Desktop on varying windows systems is to use eryksuns version:

```
@Echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (
  `powershell -c "[environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')"`
) do set "desktop=%%a"
```

Comment: Technically the "Shell Folders" registry key isn't supposed to be used. You could get this information using .NET via PowerShell: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (\`powershell -c "[environment]::getfolderpath('desktop')"\`) do @set "desktop=%%a"`.

Comment: @eryksun I agree, that is a more official way. My code stems from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45359784/6811411) primarily evaluating the relocated Downloads folder for which no other way seems to exist.

Comment: @LotPings I have modified some of the shell folder paths since Windows 95 on all my Windows machines. According to the Microsoft TechNet article about [User Shell Folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962613.aspx) and [Shell Folders](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962600.aspx) the later exists only for downwards compatibility for programs designed for Windows NT 4.0 or earlier. Windows 2000 and all later Windows version use `User Shell Folders` and update `Shell Folders` automatically sooner or later when a string value in `User Shell Folders` is modified.

Comment: @mofi Yes my first version in the refernced answer included user shell folders but to much choices seemed to iriitate more than help. Eryksun's Powershell adaption seems to be a better choice for available shell folders.

Comment: Interesting for me is also that `Shell Folders` on my Windows XP machine contains the strings `Administrative Tools` and `CD Burning` while `User Shell Folders` does not have those two string values. Also `Shell Folders` contains only string values of type `REG_SZ` with full path to each folder while `User Shell Folders` contains string values of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` containing `%USERPROFILE%` environment variable references (except those I modified). So it is easier to use `Shell Folders` in simple batch files because the folder path is already an expanded absolute path.

Comment: @Mofi Interestingly is that `[environment]::getfolderpath('nonexistent')` in PowerShell willl list valid folder names in the error message.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That is really interesting because some values in registry are not listed by PowerShell in error message and can be really not queried with this method like `NetHood` or `Fonts`. Well, they are not really user shell folders. As written in Windows 7 registry it is recommended to use [SHGetFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181.aspx) or [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx) with a [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx) as PowerShell does.