# How can I call an environment variable in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I'd like to create a batch file that creates a directory symbolic link for My Pictures - in the Downloads folder...

```
mklink /D "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Pictures" "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Saved Pictures"
```

But the above doesn't work

Comment: Do you get an error or anything? What you've posted should be correct, provided `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Saved Pictures` is the folder that already exists.

Comment: No. It just executes and closes and nothing happens. If I give the drive letter it works, but that letter could change.

Comment: Drive letter should be part of `%USERPROFILE%`... what is the output of `echo %USERPROFILE%`? It should be something like `C:\Users\Johan`.

Comment: @SomethingDark I tried it from the command line and it tells me the system can't find the path specified. Basically it's not recognizing the %USERPROFILE% variable. Because if I just type - `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Saved Pictures` into Windows explorer it does in fact exist.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the quotes

Comment: What is the output of `echo %USERPROFILE%`? Quotes won't break it unless they're already part of the variable, and they shouldn't be unless you've got a space in your username (and even then they probably aren't there).

Comment: Okay, I've discovered that - although I can use the %USERPROFILE% variable in Windows Explorer - if I go to the `C:\Users\Johan` location the folders I want are missing. (My pictures, etc.). I see them from some other directory that has the same items.

Comment: The echo output is what it should be `C:\Users\Johan` but the folders aren't there. I'm not sure where they're located. I can type `Johan` in Windows Explorer, and I go to the folder I'm looking for - and I can use `%USERPROFILE%` in Explorer - to the same effect, but they're not in `C:\Users\Johan`

Comment: The information posted in answer on [Navigating to Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45651597/3074564) and below in the comments might be helpful for you.

Comment: I think [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45359784/6811411) in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356341/evaluate-location-of-relocated-shell-folders-with-batch/45359784#45359784) is the better reference.